# A difficulty in understanding the definition for limit superior of ${x_{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limsup-and-liminf

The definition is given by the following formula:

$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n} := \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\sup_{m\geq n} x_{m}) $$

I could not understand the meaning of $(\sup_{m\geq n} x_{m})$ and why we have this number m and why it must be $\geq n$, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior) has a useful illustration.  Have you seen it? The definition is meant to discard large values that only occur early on.

Comment: I can not understand this statement of you "discard large values that only occur early on" my mother tongue is not english @FabioSomenzi

Comment: yes I looked at it but it does not have the answer of my question @FabioSomenzi

Comment: Think of it this way: if $x_{10} = 1000$, but for $m > 100$, $x_m < 100$, then $1000$ is not the $\limsup$ of the sequence.  In fact, the limit superior is at most $100$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the limit of the sequence $\sup \{x_1,x_2,...\}, \sup \{x_2,x_3,...\},\sup \{x_3,x_4,...\},...$.

Note that the sequence is non increasing (since it is the $\sup$ of a smaller and smaller set), hence it
has a limit (or is $\pm \infty$).

For example, let $x_n = (-1)^n (1+{1 \over n})$. Then $\limsup_n x_n = 1$.

Another example: Let $x_n = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if } n \text{ is a power of }2,\\
-n, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, then $\limsup_n x_n = 1$.

Comment: could u provide more details please?

Comment: Well, this is the definition. If you have specific questions I can answer. Loosely speaking it is the $\max$ (more correctly the $\sup$) of the sequence 'in the limit'.